# How to get the absolute path from an JLabel ImageIcon?

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I am creating an Photo and Video Viewer. Already made the video part, now I am making the photo part.

Trying to get the absloute path, for something like this:

[image]

And then it deletes.
I'm using a JLabel for displaying. What i tried was:

```
System.out.println("Deleting file");

ImageIcon img = (ImageIcon) showDisplay.getIcon();
System.out.println(img.toString());

File file = new File(img.toString());
int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Are you sure you want to delete the file " + file.getName() + "?");
if(response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    deleteFile(file);
    //the thing that deleteFile has is file.delete();
}
```

But this returns javax.swing.ImageIcon@6aa93db7 in the console, not the absolute path.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: Why are you casting to ImageIcon? That [has nothing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) to get the filename back out. Presumably you have a metadata object backing that icon, why not access _that_ instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `setDescription(...)` and `getDescription(...)` methods for this.

Depending on your you load the Icon this may already contain the file path.

If not, then you can manually set this value yourself when you create the image and create the Icon.

Comment: Thank you!. This will really help.